# Parse 2 different XML attributes together in a single python for loop

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I hope my title is a bit clear, as I'm not too sure how to phrase it.

I'm working on a script to pull movie titles from my Plex server's XML output, and feed them to other functions later on. I've been able to pull the `title` attribute without issue, and use it correctly in a `for` loop. I'm now trying to parse the `collection` attribute, and insert an `if/and` loop within the `for` loop for some added logic.

XML snippet I'm parsing from:

```
<Video ratingKey="1308" key="/library/metadata/1308" studio="Marvel Studios" type="movie" title="The Avengers" titleSort="Avengers" contentRating="16+" summary="When an unexpected enemy emerges and threatens global safety and security, Nick Fury, director of the international peacekeeping agency known as S.H.I.E.L.D., finds himself in need of a team to pull the world back from the brink of disaster. Spanning the globe, a daring recruitment effort begins!" rating="7" viewOffset="4433638" lastViewedAt="1397229827" year="2012" tagline="Some assembly required." thumb="/library/metadata/1308/thumb/1396546317" art="/library/metadata/1308/art/1396546317" duration="8574897" originallyAvailableAt="2012-05-04" addedAt="1393760099" updatedAt="1396546317">
<Media videoResolution="1080" id="1213" duration="8574897" bitrate="2200" width="1920" height="1080" aspectRatio="1.78" audioChannels="2" audioCodec="aac" videoCodec="h264" container="mp4" videoFrameRate="24p" optimizedForStreaming="1" has64bitOffsets="0">
<Part id="4105" key="/library/parts/4105/file.mp4" duration="8574897" file="M:\The Avengers (2012)\The Avengers (2012).mp4" size="2358359343" container="mp4" has64bitOffsets="0" optimizedForStreaming="1"/>
</Media>
<Genre tag="Action"/>
<Writer tag="Joss Whedon"/>
<Director tag="Joss Whedon"/>
<Country tag="USA"/>
<Role tag="Robert Downey Jr."/>
<Role tag="Chris Evans"/>
<Role tag="Mark Ruffalo"/>
<Collection tag="Save Me"/>
</Video>
```

Python code I currently have:

```
plex_url = 'http://localhost:32400/library/sections/2/all'
root_tree = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(plex_url))
video = root_tree.getElementsByTagName('Video')
for t in video:
    title = t.getAttribute('title') 
    global collection
    collection = root_tree.getAttribute('Collection')
    print collection
    movie_data(title)
    if Netflix() is True and collection == 'Save Me':
        print "%s is available on Netflix, but marked for saving. Moving to next movie." % movie
        continue
    elif collection != 'Save Me' and Netflix() is True:
        choice = raw_input("Netflix Streaming is available for this movie. Do you wish to mark this movie for deletion?")
        if choice in yes:
            delete_movie()
        elif choice in no:
            print "Skipping %s. Moving on to next movie." % movie
            continue
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no'")
    else:
        print "%s is not available on Netflix. Moving on to next movie." % movie
        continue
```

The issue I'm having is that even though the movie has a Collection attribute, it doesn't seem to be capturing it, so the `collection` variable is never `'Save Me'`.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a Collection attribute on the root node when really you want a Collection element with a tag attribute on the current "video" element. Instead of:

```
global collection
collection = root_tree.getAttribute('Collection')
```

try

```
collections = t.getElementsByTagName('Collection')
if collections:
    collection = collections[0].getAttribute('tag')
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm receiving an error on line 86 stating that `name 'collection' is not defined.` It seems like it's seeing a blank entry on the first pass, and can't handle it for some reason.

Comment: I don't know what your line 86 is, but it could be that not all Video elements have a Collection child. You should skip the entire record or have some useful default handling for that case. And add a print statement to see if my guess is right.